Why does getExtraNameCharacters() not include the "[]."?
In an effort to fight SQL-injection, we've implemented a validator for table-names. It checks, if the characters are all alphanumeric, or, if anything else is found, whether it is present in the string returned by the JDBC-driver's getExtraNameCharacters-method:
public static void assertNameValidity(String name, Connection conn)
    throws SQLException {
    String suspect = name.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9_]", "");
    if (suspect.isEmpty()) {
        /*
         * XXX if the name begins with a number, it may
         * XXX still be invalid, but we only care for
         * XXX SQL-injection attempts anyway...
         */
        logger.debug("{} is alphanumeric, a valid name", name);
        return;
    }
    DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
    logger.debug("'{}' contains suspect character{}: '{}'. " +
        "Checking, if {} valid for a name in {}.",
        name, suspect.length() == 1 ? "" : 's', suspect,
        suspect.length() == 1 ? "it is" : "they are",
        md.getDatabaseProductName());
    /*
     * Deal with the non-alphanumeric characters remaining -- they
     * may still be suitable in names in certain databases.
     */
    String additional = md.getExtraNameCharacters();
    for (int i = 0; i < suspect.length(); i++) {
        char c = suspect.charAt(i);
        if (additional.indexOf(c) >= 0) {
            logger.debug("Character '{}' is in '{}', " +
                "thus valid part of name", c, additional);
            continue;
        }
        logger.error("Found invalid character '{}' in \"{}\". " +
            "Neither alphanumeric, nor otherwise valid",
            c, name);
        System.exit(3); /* XXX throw SecurityException instead? */
    }
}

However, as the experience has shown, for SQL Server databases the getExtraNameCharacters() returns only these three characters: "$#@", which causes strings like [dbo].[myTable] to be rejected. As a work-around, we added the following block to the above function:
if (md.getDatabaseProductName() == "Microsoft SQL Server" &&
    additional.indexOf('[') == -1) {
    logger.info("Adding square brackets and dot to the " +
        "list of acceptable characters, because Microsoft " +
        "are lying to us returning only: '{}'", additional);
    additional += "[].";
}

Things work, but why wouldn't the result of getExtraNameCharacters() contain the dot and the square brackets in the first place?

Read the docs, getExtraNameCharacters is allowed chars for unquoted table names. You can't use []. in such. Btw, your approach is already wrong, sanitizing code for sql injection is not the way to go, sorry

The select * from [dbo].[myTable] is valid, no quotes necessary. Not sanitizing code, only checking, whether it has suspect characters, sorry.

[] are quotes. Try naming your table: [test and see how far it goes. If your code was correct, you wouldn't need to check any suspect characters, if you have dynamic sql, you should use QUOTENAME and friends to properly escape tables or even better, avoid dynamic sql altogether if possible, instead of checking for suspected chars.

"[] are quotes". Right.. Whatever you say, I suppose... :) There is no other solution for code, that has to create tables with names specified on command-line, so, please, avoid the grandstanding...

I just don't want to read about your company in the news :) And asking for sanitization and checking is often the wrong question, because it's hard to do it correctly. But yeah, if you have to do it, QUOTENAME is your friend. Btw, let's say a user enters: [Test], what does it mean, will the table be called Test or [Test].

Notably, I'm not asking about sanitization -- even if you insist on answering that...

QUOTENAME seems to be a SQL Server thing only, whereas our code tries to be driver-agnostic. Back to getExtraNameCharacters() -- are you reclassifying the dot as a "quote" too, in addition to the square brackets?

Btw, char c = suspect.charAt(i); is wrong if you handle wide chars, but yeah, i ramble on :D The answer is in the first message.

In SQL Server case, there are two ways of writing names, quoted and unquoted. The chars like [.<space>'%+- etc needs to be quoted when using them in table names, so this is probably the reason that getExtraNameCharacters aren't returning them, because they aren't allowed in unquoted names. For quoted names, all characters are allowed, so there's no point in getExtraNameCharacters functions there. Btw, i also write jdbc code for multiple vendors, and i haven't found a pure JDBC solution for safe quoting identifiers

Luckily, our table-names never include spaces, and never need actual quoting. Your "first message" is incorrect -- it insists, that a string like [dbo].[myTable] is quoted, which it obviously is not (unless "quoted" means something other than "being surrounded by quotes"). Maybe, you and I delete these comments and we wait for someone to actually answer the question?

A few notes: (1) If you allow quoted identifiers but still want to validate them, I recommend that you add a check that verifies that any embedded ] characters are paired. For example, the weird identifier Matrix[2][2]Value must be quoted as [Matrix[2]][2]]Value]. (2) Some identifiers still need to be quoted if they are reserved words. A table named [order] or a column named [default] are examples in SQL Server. (3) It may be best to just treat names (normal and weird) as plain text in your code until inserted into SQL, at which point best practice is to quote all identifiers.

It's a product-specific terminology thing. In SQL Server, both [xxx] and "xxx" are considered quoted identifiers. However, the latter requires that the SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER option be set to ON.  Various DBMSs all have their history and resulting quirks, since they evolved in parallel with but not always in sync with the various standards.

@siggemannen Since JDBC 4.3 (Java 9), there is Statement.enquoteIdentifier(String), but then you do need to use a driver overriding the default implementation (which does SQL standard quoting of identifiers), or your DBMS needs to follow the SQL standard rules for identifiers.

You're making the wrong assumption about the result of DatabaseMetaData.getExtraNameCharacters(). Its documentation states:

Retrieves all the "extra" characters that can be used in unquoted identifier names (those beyond a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _).

ISO/IEC 9075-2:2023 (the SQL standard) only specifies a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and _ as allowed in an unquoted identifier, but most DBMSes also allow additional characters. The getExtraNameCharacters() is so you can find out what those extra characters are.
However, [dbo].[myTable] is an identifier chain (it is not a simple single identifier!), consisting of two quoted identifiers, namely [dbo] and [myTable]. Those square brackets are the default quote symbols of SQL Server. As such, neither those square brackets, nor the period (.) separating the identifiers in the identifier chain are allowed in an unquoted identifier, and thus those characters are not included in the value of getExtraNameCharacters().
As an aside, I'm really wondering what kind of dynamic system with user-provided object names you're maintaining that you need to validate this at all to prevent SQL injection.

I appreciate the explanation, but not the attack about "wrong assumption". The documentation clearly says "unquoted". That [] are considered quotes in the world of SQL Server, is an idiosyncrasy of that world, not evidence of any wrongness with me.

@MikhailT. Would your question have been different if "dbo"."myTable" or dbo.myTable had been used? Even you didn't know that [ and ] are - historically - the quote characters in SQL Server, you should be aware that . is not allowed in an unquoted identifier, as it's the thing that separates identifiers in an identifier chain. And to be honest, if you're writing software targeting SQL Server, and trying to validate identifiers as a SQL injection prevention measures, I  do assume and hope that you'd know about how it quotes identifiers.
